# Find duplicate rate values on different dates

Tags: postgresql, date, duplicates

I have a rate table:

```
date
price
currency_id
```

And would like to get duplicate values on different dates, this is, see if the same rate is on different dates.

I've ran this for currency_id 15:

```
SELECT rate, COUNT(rate)
FROM rates
where currency_id =15
group by 1
HAVING COUNT(rate)>1;
```

And I get an approximation of what I need, but I would like to see the date it repeats, not just the rate and how many times it appears..

When I add the date, count is only 1 which makes sense because there's only 1 rate per date, how can I find out on what dates the rate is the same?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate all the dates in an array:

```
SELECT rate,
       COUNT(rate),
       array_agg(date)
FROM rates
where currency_id =15
group by 1
HAVING COUNT(rate)>1;
```